# How to clear out char array with memset

Tags: c++, c, buffer, memset

I'm looking for a method to clear a char array similar to how in python you would do the following:

```
buffer = ""
```

Is using memset the best approach for this, or is there another builtin function/method I'm missing?

What Ive tried:

```
 memset(buf, '\n', sizeof(char));
```

Comment: do a `memset(buf, '\0', sizeof (buf))`

Comment: `buffer = ""` doesn't clear the buffer, just assign an empty string...

Comment: and if you just logically want to clear the array out, so that it is not printed or anything, just `buf[0] = '\0'` should also suffice...

Comment: What is `buffer`? Why C and C++ ?

Comment: To show the optimum way to do it, we need an actual use case with real code and just the line that will clear the array missing. In particular, it matters *why* the array needs to be clear.

Comment: Which language, `C` or `C++`?

Answer (score 0):

Since sizeof(char) is 1, you don't need that. If the size of your char array is `s`, use the following code:

```
memset(buffer, 0, s);
```

this will write 0 on every byte from `buffer` to the next `s` bytes.

Comment: To be precise, it will behave as if it did that. It may or may not actually do that. (This might matter if, for example, the application is ensuring that something secret doesn't remain in memory longer than necessary.)